# GoogleMail classing newsletter as spam

Tags: wordpress, email, spam-prevention

I have a Wordpress website which uses the Subscribe2 plugin to send out a weekly email newsletter. Each week my newsletter has been sending out fine, but for the past two weeks, the newsletter has been caught by GoogleMail's spam filter. It goes to other addresses fine. I need to fix the Gmail problem if possible.

I'm using settings to send the emails out in batches of 30 and have employed another plugin to route the email addresses through my SMTP server instead of using the standard WP/PHP mail function. But this still hasn't helped it. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are sending more information than you need (e.g. publicity, or links to a others webs).
Have you tried to send it to a Hotmail/Yahoo account? (Is it the same result?)

Also can be for the words that you have used. The google's filter use a parser to catch the words and it use with a specific patron of sentences to see if your mail contains "bad" words.

Comment: There are a few links to other websites, but even if I remove them, it still thinks it's spam. Don't know about Hotmail but Yahoo doesnt have a problem with it.

Comment: It's posible that the filters of spam, know that before you send an email without links, your email address is in the blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Always tricky these "why does it land in the junk folder" issues...

Try adding this header:

Precedence: bulk

They it into account when classifying mails (not likely to fix your issue, but could be part of the puzzle).

Make sure you have all the "classic issues" solved, such as reverse-DNS record, and maybe SPF/SPF-2 records (you say something about using your own SMTP-server).

Try reading their postmaster info at:

https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126

and see if there is any other things you have missed.

If you need further help you could try and post the full message source, maybe someone can spot something.

Comment: Precedence is already set to 'list' with the list ID set, I believe this is the best way to do it?

Comment: Thanks I will look at the reverse-DNS and SPF things, I didn't know about those.

Comment: On the postmaster page they explicitly mention "Precedence: bulk".Lists are for a classic mailing lists, where the users send mails to the list address (not sure if any programs use that header-value for anything though).

Answer (score 0):

Full message source:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>A Little Bird: This Week We Love... 17 September 2010</title>

                                          <style type="text/css">

                                          body{

                                            background-color: #FFA6C9;
                                            margin:0;
                                            padding:0;
                                          }

                                            a{
                                                color: #275571;
                                            }

                                            th.website p{
                                                margin: 0;
                                                padding: 0;
                                            }
                                          </style>

                                          </head><body style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFA6C9" background="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/bg2.png" style="background: #FFA6C9  url('http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/bg2.png') center top repeat; ">
                <tr><td valign="top" align="center">

        <br><br>

        <table style="background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 540px; text-align: left;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 15px 0px 0px 30px;" align="left">
                    <a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com" style="border: none;"><img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/email-header-1.png" alt="A Little Bird" style="border: none;"></a>
                </td>

                <td style="padding: 15px 30px 0px 0px;" align="left">
                    <p style="margin: 22px 0 0 140px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #999;">For more suggestions please visit <a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com" style="color: #275571;">www.A-LittleBird.com</a></p>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;" align="left" colspan="2">

                    <a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com" style="border: none;"><img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/email-header-2.png" alt="THIS WEEK WE LOVE..." style="border: none;"></a>

                    <a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com" style="border: none;"><img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/email-header-3.png" alt="" style="border: none;"></a>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td style="padding: 30px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666;" colspan="2">


            <div style="margin: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/2010/09/16/restaurants-hel-yes/" style="font-size: 24px; color: #275571; text-decoration: none; line-height: 135%;">Restaurants: Hel Yes!</a>
<br><br><br>
<table style="border: 0; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666; line-height: 120%;">
                <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><img width="540" height="359" src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Hel-Yes-593x395.jpg" class="attachment-540x400 wp-post-image" alt="Hel Yes" title="Hel Yes"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><p>The latest in East London cool is a Finnish pop-up restaurant in a disused warehouse near Old Street. &nbsp;It sounds crazy, but it’s true. &nbsp;Commissioned by The Finnish Institute for the London Design Festival, there are bowed Aspen branches over the tables, light installation sculptures and trendy Finnish waiters in Heikki Salonen outfits. &nbsp;Best of all though, is the food which is part foraged locally, part sourced from Finland and changes daily. &nbsp;Think sea bass tartar with archipelago bread, lamb neck with dill and liquorice crème brûlée. They are hoping to extend their 3 week stay but until then you’ll have to hurry to get a table as they are almost booked out. &nbsp;Alternatively, turn up for a cocktail – we found the Purple Lumi, vodka and mixed forest berries, went down a treat – and the bar is open until 1am.</p>
<br><table class="postsummary" style="border: 0; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666;">
                <tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">What:</th><td>Pop-up Finnish restaurant Hel Yes!</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">When:</th><td>Wed: 5pm-1am, dinner 7-11pm; Thurs-Sat: 11am-1am, dinner 7-11pm and Sun: 12-5pm.  All until 3 October</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Where:</th><td>Londonewcastle Depot, 1-3 Wenlock Road, <a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=N1&#43;7SL" target="_blank">N1 7SL</a></td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Price:</th><td>2 courses: ₤22; 3 courses: ₤25</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Tel:</th><td>07505 998 053</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" class="website">Website:</th><td>www.helyes.fi</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
<img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/emaildots.png" alt="" style="border: none;"><br><br><br>
<div style="margin: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/2010/09/16/our-favourite-iphone-apps/" style="font-size: 24px; color: #275571; text-decoration: none; line-height: 135%;">Technology: our favourite iPhone and iPad apps</a>
<div style="line-height: 120%;"><p><strong>News:</strong> <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nyt-editors-choice/id357066198?mt=8">The New York Times</a> (free) and&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-guardian/id340425655?mt=8">The Guardian</a> (₤2.39) deliver well edited news on the go.</p>
<p><strong>Culture:</strong> <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/love-art-national-gallery/id314566159?mt=8">Love Art</a> (₤1.79) is at-your-fingertips commentary on all the National Galleryʼs pictures;&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movies/id284235722?mt=8">Flixter</a> (free) for details of where and when your favourite ﬁlms are on;&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stanza/id284956128?mt=8">Stanza</a> (free) downloads hundreds of classic books and&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itheatre/id319720681?mt=8">iTheatre</a> (free)&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gigometer/id324622636?mt=8">Gigometer</a> (₤0.59) for booking tickets wherever you are.</p>
<p><strong>General: </strong>For those truly addicted,&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ebay-mobile/id282614216?mt=8">eBay</a> (free) gives you access anytime anywhere, ditto with <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8">Facebook</a> (free) and <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-mobile/id297606951?mt=8">Amazon</a> (free); <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nearestwiki/id331305547?mt=8">Nearestwiki</a> (₤1.19) is a brilliant invention that works best in cities. &nbsp;Point your iPhone at any site of interest and it will&nbsp;give you all the local wiki information. &nbsp;In a similar vein is <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/star-walk-5-stars-astronomy/id295430577?mt=8">Star Walk</a> (₤1.79), an award winning app which will tells you which stars you are looking at. &nbsp;If you’re stuck on the tube, pass the time with <a href="http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/games/cards_puzzle/scrabble.html">Scrabble</a> (₤1.79) and if
you’re at a loss at what to cook, there is always&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/nigella-quick-collection/id366478575?mt=8">Nigella</a> (₤4.99).</p>
<div>
<p><strong>And for the iPad only</strong>:&nbsp;<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flipboard/id358801284?mt=8">Flipboard</a> (free)&nbsp;puts all your social networks such as Twitter and Facebook onto one flippable magazine. &nbsp;Very addictive.</p>
</div>
<br><table class="postsummary" style="border: 0; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666;">
                <tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" class="website">Website:</th><td><a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/">Apple</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/emaildots.png" alt="" style="border: none;"><br><br><br>
<div style="margin: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/2010/09/15/one-day-only-designer-clothing-auction/" style="font-size: 24px; color: #275571; text-decoration: none; line-height: 135%;">Shopping: Kerry Taylor Vintage Fashion and Textile Auction</a>
<div style="line-height: 120%;"><div>
<div>Kerry Taylor is the force who runs Sotheby’s couture&nbsp;auctions where frocks go for fortunes. But Taylor also runs her own auction house in South London where you can get fantastic items at much more affordable prices. We once scored a whole slew of Chanel and Ferragamo shoes for about £100. This season’s auction has a wide range of items from every decade, including loads of particularly good Ossie Clarke and some unusual 80′s pieces. You can visit Taylor’s warehouse (vintage fashion <em>heaven</em>), where everything is on display two days before the auction, or check out the lots online. You can bid online too, or by telephone, though the actual auction is always good sport, not only for the thrill of making your own bids, but because you get to see costume designers battling it out with vintage dealers.</div>
</div>
<br><table class="postsummary" style="border: 0; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666;">
                <tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">What:</th><td>Kerry Taylor's Vintage Fashion and Textiles Auction</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">When:</th><td>Auction: Tues 28 Sept, 10.30am. Viewing: Sun 26, 12-4pm &amp; Mon 27 Sept, 9.30-5pm</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Where:</th><td>Kerry Taylor Auctions LLP, Unit C25, Parkhall Road Trading Estate, 40 Martell Road, Dulwich, <a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=SE21&#43;8EN" target="_blank">SE21 8EN</a></td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Tel:</th><td>020 8676 4600</td></tr>
<tr><th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" class="website">Website:</th><td><a href="http://www.kerrytaylorauctions.com/currentsale.php" target="_blank">Kerry Taylor Auctions</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/emaildots.png" alt="" style="border: none;"><br><br><br>
<div style="margin: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/2010/09/16/and-finally-2/" style="font-size: 24px; color: #275571; text-decoration: none; line-height: 135%;">And finally...</a>
<div style="line-height: 120%;"><p>Stephen Jones is our latest guest editor. To see the inspirations behind the milliner’s latest collection, visit our website <a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/category/guest-editor/">here</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--<img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/emaildots.png" alt="" style='border: none; display: none;'/>--><img src="http://www.a-littlebird.com/wp-content/themes/js/images/emaildotsgrey.png" alt="" style="border: none;"><br><br><br>

Have a great week, <br><br>
A-LittleBird
<br><br><br><p style="font-size: 11px;"><a href="http://www.a-littlebird.com/newsletter-unsubscribe" style="color: #275571;">Click here</a> if you wish to unsubscribe to these weekly emails.</p>
</td></tr></table>
            </td></tr></table>
            </body></html>
```

Email headers:

```
    Received: from mail26.extendcp.co.uk (79.170.40.154) by exchange.outitgoes.com
 (10.0.16.102) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.0.702.0; Fri, 17 Sep
 2010 15:22:00 +0100
Received: from mail by mail26.extendcp.com with spamvirus-scanned (Exim 4.72)
    id 1Owbp8-0005UL-Ht    for joe@xxxx.com; Fri, 17 Sep 2010 15:22:00 +0100
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on
    mail26.extendcp.co.uk
X-Spam-Level:
X-Spam-Status: No, score=0.2 required=8.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,AWL,HTML_MESSAGE,
    MIME_HTML_ONLY,PRICES_ARE_AFFORDABLE autolearn=disabled version=3.2.5
X-Virus-Scanned: Yes
Received: from web136.extendcp.co.uk ([79.170.44.136]
 helo=www.a-littlebird.com)    by mail26.extendcp.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.72)    id
 1Owbp8-0005Tb-Gm    for joe@xxxx.com; Fri, 17 Sep 2010 15:21:58 +0100
Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2010 14:21:58 +0000
To: <joe@xxxx.com>
From: Preview <joe@jxxxx.com>
Subject: A Little Bird: This Week We Love... 17 September 2010
Message-ID: <ba873cc6c4f534bbf7b1335bda9d35b8@www.a-littlebird.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]
Reply-To: Preview <joe@xxxx.com>
Precedence: list
List-Id: A Little Bird
X-Mailer: PHP5.2.14
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Return-Path: joe@xxxx.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: cas1.exchange-outitgoes.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
```

Comment: You might want to move the code into the body of your question and delete this answer; the code will get burred if any other answers are upvoted. Unless this is your solution? It's somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

We published our mail queuing plug-in that will queue and throttle email. It also handles multiple SMTP accounts, and non-delivery processing. You can give it a try. We've used it on a few sites that use gMail with great results.

What we have learned through experimentation is that gMail will 'learn' a mail reputation over time.  Until your reputation is established gMail will limit your SMTP sending to 5-10 messages/recipients per half hour from external mailers.  This is much lower than the 100 recipient limit they publish in the support forum.  Using multiple gMail accounts in combination with this plug-in mitigates the issue for our clients.  Give it a try if you want.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-queues/admin/